# AS3 AIR - black screen when packaged

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

When I run the application from Flash Develop everything is fine, both in Debug and Release.

After the application is packaged and installed, I just get a black screen when run.

However if I add a 'debug' file to `applicationDirecty\META-INF\AIR\debug` the application runs normally.

What could be causing this? and how can it be solved?

Comment: Double-check that you're putting the release (non-debug) SWF in the AIR package.  Also, if you've just upgraded to AIR 3.0, try [rolling back](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/853/cpsid_85304.html) to see if that makes a difference.  AIR3 has caused problems on some systems.

Comment: It appears to be an sqlite db problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A debugging utility seemed to be causing the problem in the release build... removing calls to this solved the issue.

```
/** Gets the name of the function which is calling */
public function Log(prefix:String = "", suffix:String = "", params:* = null):void 
{
    var error:Error = new Error();
    var stackTrace:String = error.getStackTrace();     // entire stack trace
    var startIndex:int = stackTrace.indexOf("at ", stackTrace.indexOf("at ") + 1); //start of second line
    var endIndex:int = stackTrace.indexOf("()", startIndex);   // end of function name

    var lastLine:String = stackTrace.substring(startIndex + 3, endIndex);
    var functionSeperatorIndex:int = lastLine.indexOf('/');
    var ClassSeperatorIndex:int = lastLine.indexOf(':');

    var objectName:String = lastLine.substring(ClassSeperatorIndex+2, functionSeperatorIndex);
    var functionName:String = lastLine.substring(functionSeperatorIndex + 1, lastLine.length);

    trace(prefix +" " + "[" + objectName + "]" + " > " + functionName + " " + suffix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Run.bat and replace

```
set OPTIONS=-connect %DEBUG_IP%
```

with

```
set DEBUG_IP=%DEBUG_IP%
```